# How to use Electron with an existing Express application

Tags: node.js, electron

I read and tried samples like the one on https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express but still I don't understand how to convert an Express app into Electron

How can I use Electron with an existing Express application?

Take for example this Express application:

**app.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var request = require("request");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("search");
});

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.search;
    var url = "https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort=seeds&limit=15&query_term='" + query + "'";
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            //res.send(data["data"]["movies"][0]["title"]);
            res.render("results", {data: data});
            //["movies"][0]["title"]
        }
        else
        console.log(data);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("IMDB server has started");
});
```

**search.ejs**

```html
Search for a movie
    
<form action="results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**results.ejs**

```html
Results page
<ul>
    <% data["data"]["movies"].forEach(function(movie){ %>
        <li>
            <strong><%= movie["title"]%></strong> - <%= movie["year"]%>
        </li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>

<a href="/">Search again</a>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the Electron `main.js` file, you should `require` your `app.js` file to start the Express application, then create a new instance of `BrowserWindow` and load the URL that your Express application is listening on.

Note that you'll either have to hard code the IP and PORT in Electron, or export them from Express and import them into the Electron `main.js` script.

<sub>**./main.js**</sub>

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')
require('./app.js')

let mainWindow = null

function main() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()
  mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:3000/`)
  mainWindow.on('close', event => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', main)
```

<sub>**./package.json**</sub>

```json
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A description of your application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/link/to/repo",
  "keywords": [ "some","keywords" ],
  "author": "You",
  "license": "Your License",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1", // required for your specific example where `ejs` package is used
    "electron": "^3.0.9",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

Then you'll want to make sure that the `node_modules` directory is in the same directory as `main.js` and `package.json`.

Finally, you can start your Express/Electron application using:

```
> npm start
```

---

If your Express application is not in the same directory as Electron, you will have to set the `views` directory for express accordingly:

<sub>**app.js**</sub>

```
var path = require('path')
var request = require("request");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

...
```

Where `/views` is a directory relative to `app.js` that contains your views.

Comment: How can I start the server automatically when the electron app is opened?